# What is Juniper's equivalent to netcat/nc command?

Tags: juniper, netcat, command-line-interface

On Linux there is a nice tool for testing connections, bandwidth, opening temp. connections etc: `nc`

What is equivalent on Juniper firewalls?

Comment: Please clarify if you're talking about NetScreen or SRX line of firewalls, they use two VERY different operating systems.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff sorry, I was talking about NetScreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get route , get tcp , it depends on what you want to accomplish .

Please have a look here http://fir3net.com/Netscreen/juniper-commands.html and here http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/information-products/topic-collections/swcmdref-basics-services/swcmdref-basics-services.pdf

Comment: Can one of these commands listen on a "temporary" port (while the command is running)? Can one of these cmd test if a TCP port is open on a remote machine?

Comment: It seems that you only need a plain telnet command :) telnet IP:PORT

Comment: This does not allow you to measure bandwidth and only allows one way connection. I am looking for a more powerful command

Comment: Seems Juniper does not provide any tools to measure bandwidth end to end. One can only do it via the connecting clients on both sides (with the proper routing/vpn in between).

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing might be `telnet`

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is a ScreenOS question but...)

In current JunOS nc isn't there, but you can just use telnet to arbitary ports.

If you need incoming you may have some luck using inetd.